# What is the proper way to separate query string parameters in a url?

Tags: url, query-string

I need to test some XSLT that is being passed several global parameters so for example:

If I have 2 parameters: `displayNumber` and `pullDate`, and my URL is www.abcdefg.com/yyy/bbb.aspx(first parameter here)(second parameter here)

If I then want to specify a value for each parameter, is there a character that should sit between the two parameters?

Comment: This is vague. Can you post some code? XSLT cannot natively detect query string variables - they must be passed in by the environment (e.g. via PHP, or whatever you're using).

Answer (score 23):

> If I then want to specify a value for each parameter, is there a
>   character that should sit between the two parameters?

This has nothing to do with XSLT.

The syntax for specifying query-string parameters in a URL is well-known:

- The first name-value pair is preceded by a  question mark `'?'` character.
- Every next name-value pair is preceded by an ampersand `'&'` character.
- Every name-value pair has the form: `name=value`

**Example**:

```
http://www.xyz.com/somePath?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```