# QueryParam skips everything after ampersand sign

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, urlencode

Here is the function header

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/getxyz")
public Response getXyz(@QueryParam("input") String input ){

SomeClass abc = someService.getValue(input);
```

and the input value can contain ampersand as well. The issue that I'm facing is when I'm using `@QueryParam` it skips all values after the ampersand sign.

Eg: if input is `test&test` again from the browser side, it is interpreted as only `test`.

Also I'm encoding the input on the client side using `encodeURIComponent(input)`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You should encode the ampersand symbol on the browser side, use `test%26test` instead of `test&test`. If you use `encodeURIComponent` as you said, please show your query param after that encoding on the client side. It sholud be `test%26test`

Comment: Yes, I do see it as test%20%26%20test

Answer (score 2):

Query Params are seprated by **&** symbol, thats the reason it skip second test after **&** in your case. if you want both `test`, then send them as `test and test` in URL.

Also please read [What is the proper way to seperate query string parameters in a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687970/what-is-the-proper-way-to-seperate-query-string-parameters-in-a-url) , how to send query params.

Comment: But this will change the input query itself if we change '&' to 'and'. Is there a better way to parse the query params?

Comment: do you really need to pass it as `test&test` ?

Comment: if yes, then try sending it like key="test&test" ie enclose your value in double quotes.

Comment: Yes, I need it as `test&test` format? Is there anything that we can do on server side to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I was able to resolve this issue using Spring MVC framework i.e using `@RequestParam` to parse the input request. It decodes `test%20%26%20test` to `test & test` accurately.

This approach will be useful if your project is using Spring MVC along with Jersey. Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestions!